# Docker for windows 'Logon Failure'

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I am periodically getting the below error when running `docker build .` for a windows container.  Only thing i've found that can fix it is a complete system reboot.  Hoping there's some other way to fix this.  Any ideas?

```
CreateComputeSystem 194bb656d998902d6a1cacabc8f6213df878a70bf9644bb5726a5339b5644f1e: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"194bb656d998902d6a1cacabc8f6213df878a70bf9644bb5726a5339b5644f1e","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\194bb656d998902d6a1cacabc8f6213df878a70bf9644bb5726a5339b5644f1e","Layers":[{"ID":"0d961d17-3e59-57ec-b577-e2fa46e415f7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a80dd368b3b7cbd9ca1d9ee09f13abda58f99ee3eae3bb608d6c56807739b931"},{"ID":"3d9a0621-57cb-56d8-a59d-98c748f857b3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\b5b087f9597cb06979e26e9fc1a4439001d72a4f9ab728e3c0fae6bb6ca1f386"},{"ID":"2928a4c9-75fe-5800-920a-c63965ccb3e3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\d43421924da6b091e73c586c0635a8a12acacc34ea69a158d1050120c9b4224b"},{"ID":"b8d1ec89-66da-5527-a5f1-15717cd70b32","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7c34e9529e612efe1d517ee3cbb6ca41ca98192b10bb0013aa168bd15b9df836"},{"ID":"5cf70ece-e2bd-5203-942a-75ce472653b2","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e3112b599c90232a36498cd01af8208bdda3c0ae3f28a37eaaf810d75534f753"}],"HostName":"07b2112c2753","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["3af7ee72-3894-48ce-9259-fdc853db87da"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e3112b599c90232a36498cd01af8208bdda3c0ae3f28a37eaaf810d75534f753\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try running `gpupdate /force` i've found this works instead of a system restart or vm restart. This command will reapply all group policy settings, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpupdate) for more info.

Comment: was slow, but it worked, at least i can work on other things w/out having to do a full reboot. :)

Comment: Rebooting did not resolve the issue for me, but `gpupdate /force` did work. Thanks!